# Can I assign different cookies for a single page but with different url?

Tags: cookies, view, count

I am currently implementing a *basic* page count function on one of my pages. It is based on recording the cookie of users when visiting that  particular page, if the user has not visited the page before, I give him/her a cookie that last for 1 day, then increase page view by one in the database. If  the user visits the same page again on the same day, nothing happens. The following is my code:

```
<?php 
    $cookie_name = "user";
    $cookie_value = "someone";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 86400);

    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        //code that inserts into database;
        echo "Data recorded!";
    }
?>
```

The above code will be written in only one of my script which is called "image.php", in which I will have multiple images that I pull from my database, and will be listed on the URL as something like this "...image.php?image_1.jpg" and so on. The problem I have facing is that after I successfully view one of the images, and recorded the view count onto database, I am not able to do the same on another images, it is still holding the cookie from the previous page. I have tried to add specific path and even domain but they are not working as expected, for example:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 86400, '/image.php?image_1.jpg');
```

I am definitely seeing the cookie is shared across the pages as I can see the $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] is the same when I called it. but I could not figure out how to fix that, or is there a better way to do it. I appreciate all you feedbacks, sorry for my confusing English.